# asp.net access a control from static function

Tags: jquery, asp.net, static-methods

I have a webform and in that webform, I am trying to access a Panel object from a static method, but couldn't access it How can I access a Panel object from static method. Why am I trying to access the object from static? Because I am using JQUERY which only accepts static methods.

I tried to store Panel in session in Page_Load() and retrieve it from static method but it didn't work.

Comment: We just miss your question...

Comment: What's exactly your problem, have you got not working code to show, all that kind of things... **I have a webform and in that webform, I am trying to access a Panel object from a static method** is not a question.

Comment: Use Handler mecanism to access methods with JQuery, not static methods on aspx/ascx pages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably using *web method* in the aspx page to call it from jQuery `ajax()`. You could not access the controls in web method rather pass the information to your web method by `ajax` call and return the information from `web method` to jQuery ajax `callback` and perform action on panel in javascript jQuery call back function.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. What I understood is "do the job" in jquery :))

Answer (score 6):

```
public static void DoSomething()
{
    if (HttpContext.Current != null)
    {
        Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
        TextBox TextBox1 = (TextBox)page.FindControl("TextBox1");

        TextBox TextBox2 = (TextBox)page.FindControl("TextBox2");
    }
}
```

Comment: @A Programer how would it be with a Gridview

Comment: @lvxn I think you want something like this : protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in grdView.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chkbox = row.FindControl("chkbox") as CheckBox;
        Label lblJurisdiction = row.FindControl("lblJurisdiction") as Label;
        ..and so on

        //Finally retrieve the data like your normal control
        string labelText = lblJurisdiction.Text;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

I myself always using a non static function in my code behind and call it from my WebMethod and all I need to do, just put them inside my function, instead of WebMethod. To call the function from WebMethod, you should create an object of your page. For example, supose we have a page called "add.apsx" and we also have the function AddNewRecord() and a WebMethod, AddRecord(). In the AddRecord() method, you may call the AddNewRecord function as new add().AddNewRecord(), and you are free to access all your page elements from the function. I hope it helps.