# How to access the Asp Controls inside a Static Method?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Asp:code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

C#:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static Array LoadAssetAssignView() {
 string sql = "SELECT Time,Inuse FROM table4";
 using(SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection((@ "Data Source"))) {
  using(SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, Connection)) {
   Connection.Open();
   using(SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()) {
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(myReader);
    Connection.Close();
    Num1 = textbox1.text; //Error(Can't access my asp control)
    Num2 = textbox2.text;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

In my Asp Page I involved Two textbox for my requirement.But In my back end,I Can't Access the textbox in Static method .Suggest Some Ideas. Answer rather than Comments are Appreciated.

Comment: make it non-static

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access page controls inside a static method in ASP.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31514188/how-to-access-page-controls-inside-a-static-method-in-asp-net)

Comment: You can't use controls in webservice. If i am not wrong you are trying to use it in web services.  Rather than this pass values directly as parameters in method

Comment: You can't access any control in web method. You can pass values of textboxes  as parameters of static method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this out!

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
            public static Array LoadAssetAssignView()
                {
               string sql = "SELECT Time,Inuse FROM table4";
                using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection((@"Data Source")))
                    {
                     using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, Connection))
                        {
                            Connection.Open();
                            using (SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
                            {
                                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                                dt.Load(myReader);
                                Connection.Close();
                                Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
                                TextBox TextBox1 = (TextBox)page.FindControl("TextBox1");
                                TextBox TextBox2 = (TextBox)page.FindControl("TextBox2");
                                Num1=TextBox1 .text;
                                Num2=TextBox2 .text;
                   }
              }
           }
        }
```

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684974/asp-net-access-a-control-from-static-function).